# Qtp script not clicking on security warning dialog box

Tags: automation

I am auto generating scripts using qtp10.0

My application has a popup with message `The current web page is trying to open a site in your trusted site sites list. Do you want to allow this?` and I want to click `yes` on this popup. But my script is not doing this.

Can't we click on security warning `Yes` button using script in qtp 10.0?

Answer (score 1):

First of all yes you should be able to click the "yes" button with QTP 10.

Kind of hard to answer specifically without more details but I will give you some pointers on where I would look to fix the problem.

1) Make sure you have the correct identification properties stored in the object repository for the browser, the dialog and the yes button by using the object spy.

2) Not the best solution but as the browser, and therefore the Yes button, is probably not the application under test it is probably satisfactory to use the hotkey for the yes button. (if one is available). To do this the code would look something like this.

```
    'If the dialog exists
    If Browser(<BrowserName>).Dialog(<DialogName>).Exist(3) Then
        'Use hotkey to press the yes button
        Browser(<BrowserName>).Dialog(<DialogName>).Type "Y"
        'If the dialog still exists
        If Browser(<BrowserName>).Dialog(<DialogName>).Exist(1) Then
            'report failure
        Else
            'report step done or passed
        EndIf
    EndIf
```

Feel free to comment and I will attempt to help you further if you are still having problems.

Comment: or instead of using .Type "Y" could try pressing the return key like .Type micReturn